# Extract data from a historical table keeps only data with changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

[image]

and here is the log table

[image]

So as you understood, my main table contains data from a source every day. But keeps only those with changes. Thus if everyday if 100k records comming normally, but very few (<100) are really has some changes. Thus my table tracks all the records using the log ID

So when I required to extract latest data or for any date this query works well

```
select * from (select pcode,description,T.logid,extractiondate,dense_rank() 
over(partition by pcode order by extractiondate desc) rn from @temp  T 
inner join @logs L on L.logid=T.logid where 
L.extractiondate<=(select max(extractiondate) from @logs))tbl where rn=1
 order by extractiondate desc
```

[image]

So if I specify a date instead of max, I can get that days data. there is no issue.

But I have got one more requirement. Instead of date if I specify LogId, how can I achieve the same using logId.

I know I can work it using getting the Date corresponding to a log Id and supply it to my above query. But I am trying to get the same in a better way using LogId. Please help

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dfc88/1)

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking here. if you want to filter by the `LogID` what's wrong with a `WHERE`?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: What do you mean by "achieve the same using logid"?  Your question is not clear.

Comment: Please explain the requirement (and the meaning of each column) without referring to your query.  Your query contains some odd logic.  How can there be any rows that fail the following test (effectively)? `current extractiondate <= MAX(extractiondate)`  ... If you remove this `WHERE` clause, you will see the exact same result.

Comment: See the updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dfc88/9

Comment: @JonArmstrong True.. If I remove the where it will get the same result.. But if I enter any date instead of the MAX date I will get that days full data. Thats why I have added that where clause..

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry for making confused. In the query I had mentioned, I need to specify the date to get that days full data. But I am trying to get the full  data using logId instead of date. For example if there are multiple extraction on the same day, and then I specify a logID and the query should give the whole data till then..

Comment: Maybe you can show an example.  Oh.  You may want: `where L.extractiondate<=(select extractiondate from @logs WHERE logid = yourlogid)` ... I'm assuming logid is unique in @logs.  If not, you can choose `MAX(extractiondate)` as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were you attempting to do this?

```
select *
  from (
       select pcode, description, T.logid, extractiondate
            , dense_rank() over (partition by pcode order by extractiondate desc) rn
         from temp  T
         join logs  L
           on L.logid = T.logid
        where L.extractiondate <= (select MAX(extractiondate) from logs WHERE logid = 8)
       ) tbl
 where rn = 1
 order by extractiondate desc
;
```

Note: We don't need `MAX` if logid is unique in `logs`.

See: [Test case adjusted](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dfc88/10)